# C# [BeginReceive] How to receive multiple packets without overwriting the Read Buffer?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, buffer

In the code below, each socket created to represent a client connection, I instantiate *byte[] Buffer* to store the received packet buffer.

My question is: How am working with asynchronous socket, if I have a heavy flow of incoming packets of the same client, the *Buffer* will not be overwritten before being processed due to the use of *BeginReceive* (async)? In theory using *BeginReceive*, I can receive more than one socket packet followed by another managed by differents threads. Am I wrong? If the code is unsafe for that, how I can optimize it to prevent?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections;

namespace Server
{
    public class ClientConnection
    {
        public Socket connectionSocket { get; set; }
        private byte[] Buffer { get; set; }

        public ClientConnection(Socket connectionSocket)
        {
            this.connectionSocket = connectionSocket;
            this.Buffer = new byte[4096];

            connectionSocket.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), connectionSocket);
        }

        private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socketReceive = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesReceived = socketReceive.EndReceive(ar);

                // Data was read from the client socket.
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    PacketReader packetReader = new PacketReader(Buffer);

                    connectionSocket.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), connectionSocket);
                }
                else
                {
                    Disconnect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed from: " + connectionSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed from: " + connectionSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Send(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                connectionSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), connectionSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed from: " + connectionSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try 
            {
                Socket socketSend = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                socketSend.EndSend(ar); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed from: " + connectionSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            connectionSocket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem if `new PacketReader(Buffer);` copies the necessary info to its private fields....

Comment: In short, then the BeginReceive runs in a queue, not allowing the AsyncCallback(ReadCallback) is passed at the same time? Sorry for my english, I can not express my question in detail.

Comment: Gustavo, one `ReadCallback` per `BeginReceive`